# SQL query within Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, solarwinds-orion

I am trying to run a query within python and am running into errors.

I am extremely novice in the world of SQL, and one of our DBAs wrote this SQL command and it worked from their machine. However when I am converting it to Python is where I am running into issues.

```
import requests
from orionsdk import SwisClient

npm_server = 'SERVER'
username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'

verify = False
if not verify:
    from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)


swis = SwisClient(npm_server, username, password)

print("Query Test:")

query = """
SELECT NodesData.Caption as NodeName, IP_Address,
Interfaces.InterfaceName,
Interfaces.Status, Interfaces.InterfaceLastChange
 FROM Interfaces
 INNER JOIN NodesData ON Interfaces.NodeID = NodesData.NodeID
 INNER JOIN NodesCustomProperties (NOLOCK) ON NodesData.NodeID = NodesCustomProperties.NodeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN WebCommunityStrings ON WebCommunityStrings.CommunityString = NodesData.Community
 WHERE Interfaces.Status = 2 AND Interfaces.Severity > 0 AND InterfaceName = 'Tunnel201' ORDER BY NodesData.Caption, Interfaces.InterfaceIndex DESC
"""
results = swis.query(query)

for row in results['results']:
    #print("{NodeID:<5}: {DisplayName}".format(**row))
    print("{NodeID:<5}: {DisplayName}".format(**row))
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\jefhill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe "C:/Users/jefhill/Desktop/Python Stuff/Projects/solarWinds/swExport.py"
Query Test:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jefhill/Desktop/Python Stuff/Projects/solarWinds/swExport.py", line 30, in <module>
    results = swis.query(query)
  File "C:\Users\jefhill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\orionsdk\swisclient.py", line 26, in query
    {'query': query, 'parameters': params}).json()
  File "C:\Users\jefhill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\orionsdk\swisclient.py", line 63, in _req
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\jefhill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: mismatched input ')' expecting 'EQ' in Join clause for url: https://SERVER:PORT/SolarWinds/InformationService/v3/Json/Query

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Note: Removed some of the more private information (IE, server name, password, ect)

Comment: Looks like it's complaining about the `(NOLOCK)` in the query. I'm no SQL expert but after googling it looks like that's only used in Microsoft's SQL Server. I'm not sure which database you are connecting to, which is handled by the Python library you're using, but I guess it's not SQL Server.

Comment: @RobinZigmond id assume NOLOCK is not within my library - going to google that now to see if others using the same one have ran into this.

Comment: Have you tried your query on Orion SWQL studio?